# MySQL Sort One Column Select 2nd Column Values Based on some Criteria

Tags: mysql, columnsorting

I have a table very similar to that below.   I need to sort the `end_time` into ascending order and then select the `start_time` that are say within plus or minus 2 seconds of the selected `end_time` in the remaining rows.  In essence what I am trying to do is to create an end to end chain of those end_times that match starting times end to end.

So after the first match I would get the `main_id` of the `start_time` row that matched and repeat for its `end_time`.   Using this you can see that from the table below the the following links or aggregates can be found.

```
1->2
3->4
5->6->7->8
10->11
```

Now I can readily do this programmatically in say PHP by reading in the rows, but would like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this in SQL where some of the tables could be large.

```
+-------------------+------------+
|main_id|start_time |   end_time |
|-------------------+------------+
| 1      1467695616   1467695676 |
| 2      1467695677   1467695683 |
| 3      1467782122   1467782182 |
| 4      1467782181   1467782238 |
| 5      1472329347   1472329374 |
| 6      1472329375   1472329553 |
| 7      1472329554   1472329733 |
| 8      1472329734   1472329764 |
| 9      1472329949   1472330078 |
|10      1472330275   1472330453 |
|11      1472330454   1472330479 |
+----+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for your expect result

Comment: I have the first table shows the results.  Does this help?  1->2, 3->4, 5->6->7->8, 10->11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example we assign a group to each line. If the difference between the previous end_time and the current lines start_time is within +/- 2 seconds we keep the same group number, otherwise we increment the group number. This should work in all versions of MySQL.
In the second example we use windows functions `lag() over (order by ~)`, `sum(~) over(order by ~)` and a CTE so it will not work in versions of MySQL lower then 8.

> ```
> create table t (
> main_id int,
> start_time int,
> end_time int);
> insert into t values
> (1,1467695616,1467695676),
> (2,1467695677,1467695683),
> (3,1467782122,1467782182),
> (4,1467782181,1467782238),
> (5,1472329347,1472329374),
> (6,1472329375,1472329553),
> (7,1472329554,1472329733),
> (8,1472329734,1472329764),
> (9,1472329949,1472330078),
> (10,1472330275,1472330453),
> (11,1472330454,1472330479);
> ```

> ```
> set @latest  = 0;
> set @group = 0;
> select
> @group  := case when abs(start_time - @latest) <= 2
>                    then @group
>                    else @group + 1 
>                    end  "group",
> main_id, 
> start_time,
> @latest := end_time "end_time"
> from t 
> order by end_time,start_time
> ```

```
> group | main_id | start_time |   end_time
> ----- | --------| -----------| -----------|
>     1 |       1 | 1467695616 | 1467695676
>     1 |       2 | 1467695677 | 1467695683
>     2 |       3 | 1467782122 | 1467782182
>     2 |       4 | 1467782181 | 1467782238
>     3 |       5 | 1472329347 | 1472329374
>     3 |       6 | 1472329375 | 1472329553
>     3 |       7 | 1472329554 | 1472329733
>     3 |       8 | 1472329734 | 1472329764
>     4 |       9 | 1472329949 | 1472330078
>     5 |      10 | 1472330275 | 1472330453
>     5 |      11 | 1472330454 | 1472330479
>
```

> ```
> with CTE as
> (select
> case when abs(start_time - lag(end_time) over(order by end_time, start_time)) > 2 then 1 else 0 end  diff_previous,
> main_id, 
> start_time,
> end_time
> from t 
> order by end_time,start_time
> )
> select
> 1 + sum(diff_previous) over(order by end_time) as "group",
> main_id, 
> start_time,
> end_time
> from CTE
> order by end_time, start_time
> ```
>
> ```
> group | main_id | start_time |   end_time
> ----: | ------: | ---------: | ---------:
>     1 |       1 | 1467695616 | 1467695676
>     1 |       2 | 1467695677 | 1467695683
>     2 |       3 | 1467782122 | 1467782182
>     2 |       4 | 1467782181 | 1467782238
>     3 |       5 | 1472329347 | 1472329374
>     3 |       6 | 1472329375 | 1472329553
>     3 |       7 | 1472329554 | 1472329733
>     3 |       8 | 1472329734 | 1472329764
>     4 |       9 | 1472329949 | 1472330078
>     5 |      10 | 1472330275 | 1472330453
>     5 |      11 | 1472330454 | 1472330479
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a5f0e77c5057d77d753bded48608fb3)*

Comment: Btw, it would be great if you could share how the @group function works.   I can understand the logic but not the mechanism, i.e where is the loop?

Comment: The instructions in the select are run for each row. Have a look at the last query in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eb03311e5c9696856493c971bf3e8c03

Comment: Heads up, this  won't handle gaps in the ids.  The @variable solution can be updated `else @group = main_id` to handle them.  Not familiar enough with CTEs to say about the second.

Comment: If there is a gap in the id and a missing value we will change the group if there is 2 seconds difference. If you have a better logic to suggest I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland   Chris, I have just checked it and there does not appear to be a problem that I can detect.

Comment: Renumber the main_ids in the source data so that there is a gap, like 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9...etc.  The incrementation by 1 will fail under those conditions.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland I've removed a number and it's still working OK in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf16434750e027fd3437164eb327e750 .  Please can you explain the problem?

Comment: @ChrisStrickland Alexander - sorry I still can't see the problem??

Comment: Sorry @Kendle - I made a mistake.   I still don't see the problem either.   My comment above overlooked the fact that I had changed the main_id values :-(  The orders are identical and the grouping are also identical both in the db<>fiddle and MySQL workbench.